# Google places API didn't return photos which I could receive using map search at google.com

Tags: google-places-api, photos

Example: 
https://www.google.ru/maps/place/Florida+Auto+Exchange+Stadium/@28.00351,-82.786822,103m

There is 6 photos.

I made request:
    curl 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Florida+Auto+Exchange+Stadium&key=API_KEY'
(If you want to repeat – replace "API_KEY" with your key)

When I made this request, I've got some results and I selected the most relevant from them:

```
{
    "formatted_address" : "373 Douglas Avenue, Dunedin, FL 34698, United States",
    "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 28.00351,
            "lng" : -82.786822
        }
    },
    "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/stadium-71.png",
    "id" : "bc141a4d688b00041af65be8593aac94085031fe",
    "name" : "Florida Auto Exchange Stadium",
    "opening_hours" : {
        "open_now" : false,
        "weekday_text" : []
    },
    "place_id" : "ChIJfU3XaXDxwogRuyuZ0ob7WRU",
    "rating" : 4.2,
    "reference" : "CnRwAAAAPabBIPRwUbQHv7yvC1V7SFKFi5dBQaxRr6QIaBxdrGdmnjAw0AigFDuHEh7p55PCIBbBFvFEkfKy6PWmPW6k0o6jX55dmkSAaARtBpi6wS_RXwnNplDVly1IAlQG_lYr81VjgOyhNF3VuQHkFIttiBIQkFCBUvBPsvGic7ujR-Vn5xoUqn2aMo2MM4kyOgdBthedjnctjKo",
    "types" : [ "stadium", "establishment" ]
}
```

After I made another request:
    curl 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJfU3XaXDxwogRuyuZ0ob7WRU&key=API_KEY'
(again you could replace API_KEY and repeat this request)

Result was:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "373",
            "short_name" : "373",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Douglas Avenue",
            "short_name" : "Douglas Ave",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Dunedin",
            "short_name" : "Dunedin",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Florida",
            "short_name" : "FL",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United States",
            "short_name" : "US",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "34698",
            "short_name" : "34698",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003e373 Douglas Avenue\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eDunedin\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"region\"\u003eFL\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003e34698\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUnited States\u003c/span\u003e",
      "formatted_address" : "373 Douglas Avenue, Dunedin, FL 34698, United States",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "(727) 733-9302",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 28.00351,
            "lng" : -82.786822
         }
      },
      "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/stadium-71.png",
      "id" : "bc141a4d688b00041af65be8593aac94085031fe",
      "international_phone_number" : "+1 727-733-9302",
      "name" : "Florida Auto Exchange Stadium",
      "opening_hours" : {
         "open_now" : false,
         "periods" : [
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 1,
                  "time" : "0900"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 2,
                  "time" : "0900"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 3,
                  "time" : "0900"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 4,
                  "time" : "0900"
               }
            },
            {
               "close" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "1700"
               },
               "open" : {
                  "day" : 5,
                  "time" : "0900"
               }
            }
         ],
         "weekday_text" : [
            "Monday: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm",
            "Tuesday: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm",
            "Wednesday: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm",
            "Thursday: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm",
            "Friday: 9:00 am – 5:00 pm",
            "Saturday: Closed",
            "Sunday: Closed"
         ]
      },
      "place_id" : "ChIJfU3XaXDxwogRuyuZ0ob7WRU",
      "rating" : 4.2,
      "reference" : "CnRwAAAAikHz066f7xfohvJ8KYLEBcTDWKHQYP9ZVRYs9HmFV34j3w_dihMG5867XSpw32ey0S_S3Ut_Uf2UuqinhR08L0lLAtB4sKsXUqBoQ4SbSpdLWFLUCIV1mxgOLsATnmVlTB4odjDjaeF25v4O7h5OhRIQl6TIEpKwz4UjWlo9eNy0DhoU2_ZQFLDpW87LofAoRJ9l12fyhGQ",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Johnny Stratford",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/100251556301733609943",
            "language" : "en",
            "rating" : 5,
            "text" : "Have always loved coming here! Wonderful place for baseball.",
            "time" : 1411958723
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "appeal"
               },
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "facilities"
               },
               {
                  "rating" : 3,
                  "type" : "service"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Josh McEnany",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/112457746156632317543",
            "language" : "en",
            "rating" : 5,
            "text" : "Nice little stadium. Not one of the best in Florida for spring training, but still OK. No cupholder's and no shade. No berm or concourse in outfield. Tons of beer to choose from. 6.50-750 prices of beer. Good food selection. ",
            "time" : 1363487012
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 1,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "A Google User",
            "language" : "en",
            "rating" : 3,
            "text" : "Now called FL Auto Exchange Stadium - Small, crowded stadium with non folding seats making it a struggle for anyone wanting in and out of a row since there is no room for yours legs when others are passing by.  They started replacing the seats with fold up ones -down the right field line only.  To me this is a huge dissatisfier and a pain during the game.  Food seems expensive to me since none is allowed into the park: $3.50 water, $6 domestic beers, $6.50 cheeseburger, $3.50 plain hot dog, etc. They finally stared taking credit cards this year - used to be cash only.  Not a lot of concourse seating for eating food.  However, since this is a small venue, you can see the players up close and personal.  Not really a bad seat in the house. The first base side gets the shade first starting from the top rows and working its way down.  Third base side(visitor's dugout)  faces the sun all game long.  Just think the town and the Blue Jays could spend some money sprucing it up to 2012 standards.  Parking in the stadium is $15, across the street and surrounding area $10.  Some lawns $5.  Or, you can park downtown and walk the Pinellas Trail over to the stadium.  Tourists who come to sunbathe usually are sunburnt pretty quickly.  Bring long sleeves, a hat and sunscreen.",
            "time" : 1331301590
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 2,
                  "type" : "overall"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "Lawrence Upton",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/101518544719963117626",
            "language" : "en",
            "rating" : 4,
            "text" : "",
            "time" : 1426616377
         },
         {
            "aspects" : [
               {
                  "rating" : 2,
                  "type" : "appeal"
               },
               {
                  "rating" : 2,
                  "type" : "facilities"
               },
               {
                  "rating" : 2,
                  "type" : "service"
               }
            ],
            "author_name" : "César Antonio Alcántara Mateo",
            "author_url" : "https://plus.google.com/105971571173742757799",
            "language" : "en",
            "rating" : 4,
            "text" : "",
            "time" : 1362590023
         }
      ],
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "stadium", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://plus.google.com/111574202902721584140/about?hl=en-US",
      "user_ratings_total" : 6,
      "utc_offset" : -240,
      "vicinity" : "373 Douglas Avenue, Dunedin",
      "website" : "http://dunedin.bluejays.milb.com/index.jsp?sid=t424"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

There is absolutely no photos. Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue.  Unfortunately sometimes the Places API will omit photos or other information that is visible through the Google Maps site.  We're actively working on improving that, including the specific example in this question.

Note that since this question was originally asked, the Google Places API now returns some photos for this place (although many photos displayed by Google Maps are still missing).

Comment: The same for "Torud, Iran", placeid "ChIJD7gs9s5pnj8R0uXCjG4s79E"